# Python - Adding an extra row to an array parameter

Tags: python, arrays, parameters

I need to modify an  array parameter of a function
to add it a row of 0.

MNWE :

```
import numpy as np

def addrow(A):
    n,p = A.shape
    temp = np.zeros((n+1,p))
    temp[:n,:] = A
    A = temp
```

I understand that the last line define A as a local variable
but `A[:,:]=temp` raise an error as the shapes don't match.
Any idea without turning A in a global variable?

Thanks

Comment: Numpy has a `pad` function that's good for stuff like this.

Comment: When working with `numpy`, the usual approach is returning a new object (i.e. `return np.zeros((n+1,p))`)

Comment: I want to avoid `A=addrow(A)` if possible

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
>>> x = np.arange(12).reshape((4, 3))
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
>>> shape = x.shape
>>> np.append(x, np.zeros(x.shape[1])).reshape(shape[0] + 1, shape[1])
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.],
       [ 9., 10., 11.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>>
```

Comment: I know how to add a row of 0, my concern is to make it on an array **parameter** (for other purposes). In short to make my function `addrow` do the job.